# how to run / build golang asm file?

Tags: go, assembly, build, recompile

As I can compiling go file to asm using:

go tool compile -S hello.go > hello.s

But, how can I run / build this hello.s to binary file ?

Comment: As far as I know you can't.This assembly output is for debug purposes only.

Comment: @fuz Thx, by the way, it's possible that build an binary using go binary ? Wht I mean is I build a go file and this binary can generate another binary dynamically.

Comment: @user13935203 The go tool itself was written in Go, so it's a binary that was written in Go, and it generates binaries, so it's possible :)

Comment: @user13935203 How would you like to generate that other binary?

Comment: @icza Thx, I have to learn go tool source code.(ꏿ᷄౪ ꏿ᷄ ̨ )͞

Comment: @fuz For example, I got this situation, I have a server and this server can generate his clients with some dynamic parameters.

Comment: @user13935203  I don't quite understand.  Why do you think you need to generate a binary in this situation?  This sounds very much like a solution that's only going to cause frustration down the road.